# How to update gps in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gps, vuforia

I am currently working on ar game through Unity. I am making the game using Vuforia sdk.
GPS coordinates are required within the game, but gps coordinates are not updated. 
The strange thing is that in a single application that uses gps code only to display coordinates on the screen, gps coordinates are updated correctly, but if I put the same code into the game, the gps coordinates are no longer updated at the beginning of the application.
I don't think that's a problem with code. Please help.

public class GPSCheck : MonoBehaviour{

```
public static double first_Lat;
public static double first_Long;
public static double current_Lat;
public static double current_Long; 

private static WaitForSeconds second;

private static bool gpsStarted = false;

private static LocationInfo location;

private void Awake()
{
    second = new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
}

IEnumerator Start()
{

    if (!Input.location.isEnabledByUser)
    {
        Debug.Log("GPS is not enabled");
        yield break;
    }


    Input.location.Start(5f, 10f);
    Debug.Log("Awaiting initialization");


    int maxWait = 20;
    while (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Initializing && maxWait > 0)
    {
        yield return second;
        maxWait -= 1;
    }

    if (maxWait < 1)
    {
        Debug.Log("Timed out");
        yield break;
    }


    if (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Failed)
    {
        Debug.Log("Unable to determine device location");
        yield break;

    }
    else
    {

        location = Input.location.lastData;
        first_Lat = location.latitude * 1.0d;
        first_Long = location.longitude * 1.0d;
        gpsStarted = true;


        while (gpsStarted)
        {
            location = Input.location.lastData;
            current_Lat = location.latitude * 1.0d;
            current_Long = location.longitude * 1.0d;
            yield return second;
        }
    }
}

public static void StopGPS()
{
    if (Input.location.isEnabledByUser)
    {
        gpsStarted = false;
        Input.location.Stop();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to gps update in unity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53375765/how-to-gps-update-in-unity)

Comment: Why did you open a new question asking exactly the same thing again?

Answer (score 0):

First : you don't start your coroutine.

Second : Avoid using Unity methode as coroutine.

Try this :

```
public static double first_Lat;
public static double first_Long;
public static double current_Lat;
public static double current_Long; 

private static WaitForSeconds second;

private static bool gpsStarted = false;

private static LocationInfo location;

private void Awake()
{
    second = new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
}

private void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(GSP());
}

private IEnumarator GSP()
{
    if (!Input.location.isEnabledByUser)
    {
        Debug.Log("GPS is not enabled");
        yield break;
    }


    Input.location.Start(5f, 10f);
    Debug.Log("Awaiting initialization");


    int maxWait = 20;
    while (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Initializing && maxWait > 0)
    {
        yield return second;
        maxWait -= 1;
    }

    if (maxWait < 1)
    {
        Debug.Log("Timed out");
        yield break;
    }


    if (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Failed)
    {
        Debug.Log("Unable to determine device location");
        yield break;

    }
    else
    {

        location = Input.location.lastData;
        first_Lat = location.latitude * 1.0d;
        first_Long = location.longitude * 1.0d;
        gpsStarted = true;


        while (gpsStarted)
        {
            location = Input.location.lastData;
            current_Lat = location.latitude * 1.0d;
            current_Long = location.longitude * 1.0d;
            yield return second;
        }
    }
}

public static void StopGPS()
{
    if (Input.location.isEnabledByUser)
    {
        gpsStarted = false;
        Input.location.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: This code also does not update gps coordinates in my game..T.T

Comment: In a gps test application, can a code that works well not go back to the game? Even if the code is completely identical?

Comment: @Samuel Thauvin Apouchkal what is the reason to not use `Start` as an `IEnumerator` in this case if anyway the only thing it does is starting the coroutine? If `Start` is defined as `IEnumerator` Unity automatically starts it as Coroutine instead of a method call.

Comment: It's even what they use [as example](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LocationService.Start.html)

Comment: it's an IEnumerator Start()

not an void Start()

Comment: @SamuelThauvinApouchkal ... yeah? Thats my point ... `IEnumerator Start()` is valid code

Comment: Start is one of the few Unity methods that allows you to use it as either void or IEnumerator.  There is no reason not to use Start as an IEnumerator.

Comment: There is no reason in this case not to use start as an IEnumerator.